Constant Model as a CustomLogisticRegressionModel spark
I am trying to register a constant model in Databricks. I am trying to use a CustomLogisticRegressionModel with no input columns, one output column and only an intercept (my constant value).
Like so:
appl_mdl = CustomLogisticRegressionModel(
   
    predictionCol="pd_score",
    defaultCol=defaultCol,
    intercept=applications_params["constant"]["value"],
    
)

applications_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[appl_mdl, appl_cal])

Then I fit my pipeline in order to register a model. When i try to apply the model i get an error
I am trying to register a constant model in Databricks. I am trying to use a CustomLogisticRegressionModel with no input columns, one output column and only an intercept (my constant value).
Like so:
appl_mdl = CustomLogisticRegressionModel(
   
    predictionCol="pd_score",
    defaultCol=defaultCol,
    intercept=applications_params["constant"]["value"],
    
)

applications_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[appl_mdl, appl_cal])

Then I fit my pipeline in order to register a model:
applications_pipeline_mdl = applications_pipeline.fit(
    df.filter(F.expr("application_ind = 1"))
)

And finally i want to apply my model but get an error:

Code:
df_appl = applications_pipeline_mdl.transform(
    df.filter(F.expr("application_ind = 1"))
)

Error:
IllegalArgumentException: null does not exist.
